# Yii2 Advanced installation throws error 'Document root "/var/www/html/project/console/web" does not exist.' while running php Yii serve

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I have tried yii2 advanced installation, it works and the pages have been created. But to verify installation I used the command PHP YII serve. it throws the error

> Document root "/var/www/html/highwaymotels/console/web" does not exist.

But when I check the advanced template [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/tree/master/console) it has the same folder as mine. Am I doing anything wrong? else what is the issue here?

Comment: please check your entry script path is `@app\web`, if not please set path when use run command like `php yii serve --docroot = "@app"`. Please view [github issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/191)

Answer (score 27):

yii serve --docroot="frontend/web/"

Comment: Thank you!
The Yii documentation also forgets to mention the init command in the advanced documentation.  One can also still add the port number if your trying to follow the documentation.

    `php ./init
    php yii serve --docroot="frontend/web/" --port=8888`

Comment: thank you. it must be silly for those yii2 users :)
but it help us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by recreating the **config/console.php** file than I deleted by wanting to minimize the size of the PHP project.

```
<?php
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'my-yii-application-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params
];

return $config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Document Root Path to : var/www/html/project/frontend/web.
It worked for me.There is no console/web directory if you look into the  yii2 project installation.

Answer (score 0):

if you used composer to install yii2 .
and use `yiisoft/yii2` maybe youre dealing with this issue to solve just install using `yiisoft/yii2-app-basic` repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already done php./init, then write this: `php yii serve --docroot="frontend/web"`. Remember this: don't put `"/"` at the end of `"web"`.