# Project in Yii2 cloned does not work for me locally

Tags: yii

I've never worked with Yii, only with Laravel, java, .Net and c#. The thing is that they gave me a project to make some modifications but I can't make it run locally in windows.

I configured the paths in Xampp, I tried to occupy php yii serve but it throws me an error with the web folder that does not exist nor I know that it calls in that folder.

[image]

Someone who could guide me to make it work for me, please.

These are all the folders that were installed when I cloned the project, I executed the composer was updated and installed the dependencies

[image]

Comment: It does not look like standard Yii app. You may try something like `./yii serve --docroot="@app"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254845/yii2-advanced-installation-throws-error-document-root-var-www-html-project-co Hope above link will be useful to you